# split a dataframe with numbers separated by the add sign '+' into new rows

Tags: r, split

Sorry for the naive question but I have a dataframe like this:

```
  n sp   cap
1 1  a     3
2 2  b 3+2+4
3 3  c     2
4 4  d   1+5
```

I need to split the numbers separated by the add sign ("+") into new rows in order to the get a new dataframe like this below:

```
  n sp cap
1 1  a   3
2 2  b   3
3 2  b   2
4 2  b   4
5 3  c   2
6 4  d   1
7 4  d   5
```

How can I do that? strsplit?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, 'cap', sep="+", 'long')
#    n sp cap
#1: 1  a   3
#2: 2  b   3
#3: 2  b   2
#4: 2  b   4
#5: 3  c   2
#6: 4  d   1
#7: 4  d   5
```

Or could do this in `base R`. Use `strsplit` to `split` the elements of "cap" column to substrings, which returns a list (`lst`), Replicate the rows of dataset by the length of each list element, subset the dataset based on the new index, convert the "lst" elements to "numeric", `unlist`, and `cbind` with the modified dataset.

```
lst <- strsplit(as.character(df1$cap), "[+]") 

df2 <- cbind(df1[rep(1:nrow(df1), sapply(lst, length)),1:2],
              cap= unlist(lapply(lst, as.numeric)))
```